# How to include a .c file in my XNA project for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a game for Windows Phone using the XNA framework. I want to add a .c file to my project, but I'm not getting a solution for it. Can anyone tell me how to add it/access it?

Comment: That's not possible, you cannot run C code on a phone.

Comment: I have a c program which returns a string on my string input.This C program is a separate file.I have already implemented it using android and iPhone.Now i want to do the same in windows phone.

Comment: I guess I'll have to be more specific.  You cannot run C code on a *Windows* phone.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious option would be to reimplement the C method in C# (or VB.Net if you prefer) and call it like that. The apps on Windows Phone are sandboxed, and cannot run any "native" code.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you have to implement you C code in any language that can be compiled to .Net CF IL (C#, VB.Net, F# etc.). Or you can wait roughly 5 months for WP8 which is very likely to run some C/C++ code.

Comment: You've got a much better crystal ball there than me, especially as Microsoft have said *nothing* publicly about any possible Windows Phone 8 (in fact, it is one of the things they explicitly say to not ask about at the WP7 dev camps)